# should I add DB, API and FE in one docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project FE, BE and a DB.
now all the tutorials I found use the three in one file.

Now should it be the DB in one docker-compose file and the BE and FE in another?
Or should it be one file per project with DB, FE and BE?

[UPDATE]

The stack I'm using is Spring Boot, Postgres and Angular.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post. You should, in most cases, keep all three components in the same docker-compose.yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically your application has two parts.  The front-end runs in the browser, and it makes HTTP requests to the back-end.  The database is an implementation detail of the back-end and not something you separately need to manage.

So I'd consider two possible Compose layouts:

1. This is "one application", and there is one `docker-compose.yml` that manages all of it.
2. The front- and back-end are managed separately, since they are two separate components with a network API.  You have a `frontend/docker-compose.yml` that manages the front-end, and a `backend/docker-compose.yml` that manages the back-end and its associated database.

Typical container style is *not* to have a single shared database.  Since it's easy to launch an isolated database in a container, you'd generally have a separate database per application (or per microservice if you're using that style).  Of the options you suggest, a separate Compose file only launching a standalone database is the one I'd least consider.

You haven't described your particular tech stack here, but another consideration is that you may not need a container for the front-end.  If it's a plain React application, the "classic" development flow of compiling it to static files and publishing them via any convenient HTTP service still works with a Docker-based backend.  You get some advantages from this path like Webpack's hashed build files, so you can avoid disrupting running clients when you push out a new build.  If you separate the front- and back-ends initially, then you can change the way the front-end is deployed without affecting the back-end at all.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I use Spring Boot, Postgres and Angular. Will update the post. Thanks.